# Is there a way to put a NavigationView inside a ScrollView?

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I put a NavigationView inside a ScrollView, the result is blank in the canvas. Whereas if it is outside of the ScrollView then it is visible. This is what I mean by one inside the other:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    NavigationLink("another view", destination: ChildView())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to put a `NavigationView` in a `ScrollView`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm have a view with some options, buttons to do things, and I use the `ScrollView` to move to a certain part of the view when something changes. I also want to have two links to other views in this setup. This current design is provisional, so I'm totally open to organising things a different way.

Comment: Why is this too different to just a `List`? You can add buttons to rows, text, anything really. You can scroll the `List` too. You may also do a `ScrollView` & `ScrollViewReader` approach - whatever it is, it should be **inside** of the `NavigationView`.

Comment: Glad it worked - I've added a full answer now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is this too different to just a `List`?

With a `List`, you can add to rows `Button`s, `Text`, `NavigationLink`s, anything really. You can scroll the `List` too (if it is long enough).

You may also do a `ScrollView` & `ScrollViewReader` approach - whatever it is, it should be inside of the `NavigationView`. It doesn't make sense to put the `ScrollView` *outside* of the `NavigationView`, because the `NavigationView` is what gives your screen a title at the top and why would that be scrolled?

These examples both have this `ChildView`:

```
struct ChildView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Destination")
    }
}
```

#### Example with `List`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Text")

                Button("Button") {
                    print("press")
                }

                NavigationLink("Another view", destination: ChildView())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

#### Example with `ScrollView` & `ScrollViewReader`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                ScrollViewReader { reader in
                    Button("Scroll to random item") {
                        reader.scrollTo(Int.random(in: 0 ..< 100))
                    }

                    ForEach(0 ..< 100) { index in
                        Text("Item: \(index + 1)").id(index)
                    }

                    NavigationLink("Another view", destination: ChildView())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to make, you can use a NavigationView and initialize it like the following

```
struct CalendarView: View {
    @State private var activeView: String? = "First View"
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("First View"), tag: "First View", selection: $activeView) { EmptyView() }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Second View"), tag: "Second View", selection: $activeView) { EmptyView() }
                List {
                    Button("Go to first View") {
                        self.activeView = "First View"
                    }
                    Button("Go to second View") {
                        self.activeView = "Second View"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably also need a `VStack` that wraps the `NavigationLink`s and `List`, otherwise it might not all be on one page